# Compressing assets in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, yui-compressor

I have following configurations in production.rb

```
 # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Choose the compressors to use
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true
```

But when the ruby on rails application on production server I get following error:

```
Error compiling CSS asset

LoadError: cannot load such file -- yui-compressor
```

on commenting line `LoadError: cannot load such file -- yui-compressor`,everything goes well.
All I need a compressor that gzip compress assets before sending to improve performance!
so,what is problem here or is there any other alternative?

**Update:**
 Also javascript compression is not working,as yslow plugin for firefox also showing javascripts needs to be compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the **compression must be enabled on webserver** to have effect.
All that is needed is to add following:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

in `<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>` directive for Apache(phusion passenger) for my case.

Answer (score 8):

Have you included the [yui-compressor](http://rubygems.org/gems/yui-compressor) gem in your Gemfile? If not, then include it, run 'bundle install', and then Rails should be able to find it.

Comment: Yes,I have included yui-compressor gem in Gemfile and `run bundle install`.The irb also showing same error.