# What am I doing wrong? Pushing to Heroku fails for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I've tried pushing to Heroku numerous times even when updating the bundler. If so, what can I look out for to avoid this later? I finished ironing out the homepage on one branch and merged it to the master branch after, Im not sure if that would effect pushing to Heroku this way. Here is the compiler error:

```
 -----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
       Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/.
       Using rake 12.3.1
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Using minitest 5.11.3
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using builder 3.2.3
       Using erubi 1.7.1
       Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Using crass 1.0.4
       Using rack 2.0.5
       Using nio4r 2.3.1
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Using mini_mime 1.0.0
       Using arel 9.0.0
       Using mimemagic 0.3.2
       Using execjs 2.7.0
       Using msgpack 1.2.4
       Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Using ffi 1.9.25
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Using method_source 0.9.0
       Using thor 0.20.0
       Using multi_json 1.13.1
       Using pg 0.20.0
       Using puma 3.11.4
       Fetching rails-assets-particles.js 2.0.0
       Using tilt 2.0.8
       Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
       Using i18n 1.0.1
       Using tzinfo 1.2.5
       Using nokogiri 1.8.2
       Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
       Using rack-test 1.0.0
       Using sprockets 3.7.1
       Using mail 2.7.0
       Using marcel 0.3.2
       Using bootsnap 1.3.0
       Fetching autoprefixer-rails 8.6.2
       Using uglifier 4.1.11
       Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using turbolinks 5.1.1
       Using activesupport 5.2.0
       Using loofah 2.2.2
       Using sass-listen 4.0.0
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using globalid 0.4.1
       Using activemodel 5.2.0
       Using jbuilder 2.7.0
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Using sass 3.5.6
       Using activejob 5.2.0
       Using activerecord 5.2.0
       Using actionview 5.2.0
       Using actionpack 5.2.0
       Using actioncable 5.2.0
       Using actionmailer 5.2.0
       Using activestorage 5.2.0
       Using railties 5.2.0
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Installing rails-assets-particles.js 2.0.0
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 8.6.2
       Fetching jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
       Installing jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
       Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Fetching rails-ujs 0.1.0
       Installing rails-ujs 0.1.0
       Using rails 5.2.0
       Using sass-rails 5.0.7
       Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Bundle complete! 25 Gemfile dependencies, 67 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (5.07s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       rake aborted!
       LoadError: cannot load such file -- yui/compressor
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/autoload/yui.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:39:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:24:in `new'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:24:in `instance'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_40edd89d96f18851fbc339e9140d4bb4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: This is the error: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- yui/compressor`

Comment: I installed yui  compressor in my gemfile but it still gives me the same complier error as above

Comment: Check out the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054158/compressing-assets-in-ruby-on-rails-3

Comment: I found the answer! I installed yui compressor and yarn, deleted my gemlock file then rebundled. Then did this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939496/nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-when-pushing-to-heroku because I got a NilMethod.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using yarn on your project, just open bin/yarn on your app root folder and comment out all lines there.